# Groß-Kleinschreibung bei getrennten Hauptwörtern

Tags: noun, capitalization

> Bitte versuchen Sie es mit einem anderen Suchbegriff oder -kriterium erneut.

"-kriterium" steht hier für "Suchkriterium", also wäre mein Reflex, das "k" kleinzuschreiben, ganz so, als ob man das Wort am Zeilenende getrennt hätte. Ist das richtig, oder muss hier "Kriterium" großgeschrieben werden? Wie lautet die genaue Regel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Das Wort wird so geschrieben, wie man es schreiben würde, wenn man den Bindestrich (in diesem Fall *Ergänzungsstrich* genannt) durch das ausgelassene Wort ersetzen würde. In diesem Fall wäre das Wort "Suchkriterium", also bleibt das "k" klein. Das lässt sich zumindest aus den Beispielen in [Regel 31](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/bindestrich#K31) ableiten.

Answer (score 6):

> ...das "k" kleinzuschreiben, ganz so, als ob man das Wort am Zeilenende getrennt hätte.

Ganz genau so ist es. Der fehlende Wortteil, hier "Such", wird durch einen Bindestrich ersetzt, und das, was übrigbleibt, wird genau so geschrieben, als ob nichts davon abgetrennt wäre.

Fehlt wie hier der Anfang eines Wortes, muss der verbleibende Teil kleingeschrieben werden.